# Incrementar um array com foreach PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Eu tenho um `foreach` que onde eu preciso acrescentar o valor da variável a um `array`:

```php
foreach ($xml->NFe->infNFe->det as $itens){    
    $quantidade = round($itens->prod->qCom);
    $total_quant_unidade = array();
    array_push($total_quant_unidade, $quantidade);
}
```

O problema é que apenas o ultimo valor é acrescentado mesmo estando dentro do `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variável total_quant_unidade deve estar fora do foreach

```
$total_quant_unidade = array();

foreach ($xml->NFe->infNFe->det as $itens){    
    $quantidade = round($itens->prod->qCom);
    array_push($total_quant_unidade, $quantidade);
}
```

Comment: foi burrice minha eu estava criando o array toda vez que o foreach passava , muito obrigado